# Selenium hangs (timeout) when taking screenshot in Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

When changing the platform from Windows 10 to Linux Ubuntu, selenium screenshot function hangs (Timed Out) and give me the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myproject.py", line 482, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('item_core').screenshot(img_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 585, in screenshot
    png = self.screenshot_as_png
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 567, in screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.screenshot_as_base64.encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 557, in screenshot_as_base64
    return self._execute(Command.ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
```

The code perfectly works in Windows 10. Selenium freezes the element to take a screenshot (like what it does in Windows 10), but it hangs there.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('item_core').screenshot(img_path)
```

I'm using `ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106` and `Google-Chrome 80.0.3987.122` on `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`